# Can I get a Portuguese invitation-based visa without having a 'Termo de Responsabilidade'?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, portugal, invitation-letters

I am an Indian national, and my friend in Portugal has invited me to stay at his place there, while I visit him. All my other documents were fine, but he couldn't give me a *Termo de Responsabilidade* (Terms of Responsibility) form. He has however, sent me a formal invitation letter which he has signed, and in which he has taken responsibility for me during my trip. He has also sent a full colour copy of his Portuguese National ID card, as well as a proof of his address.

Will not having the Terms of Responsibility form cause an issue for my visa to be granted?

Comment: Does the form require it be signed/attested by any of the local bodies ? If yes, then chances are the application will be refused. And why couldn't he give you the form, if he can send you a copy of his ID card ?

Comment: According to what he told me, that form is one provided when a resident there (not a national) wants to invite a family member to stay. Since he is both a national, and just my friend, not family, it is not needed...Also, he isn't sponsoring my trip in any way. I am taking up all the needed expenses by myself...

Answer (score 1):

The [Termo de Responsabilidade](http://www.sef.pt/documentos/57/TERMODERESPONSABILIDADEFronteiras.pdf) appears (according to Google Translate) to be roughly equivalent to the German *Verpflichtungserklärung* -- it is a document where the host *guarantees* to the government to cover the traveler's expenses and agrees that the government can hit *him* with the bill if you end up needing care/lodging on public expense, or if you overstay and they have expenses expelling you etc.

It makes sense that a causal friend, even one who is prepared to let you crash on his couch for a few days, will not want to risk that.

Such documents are primarily used to help applicants who *can't qualify for a visa based on their own circumstances* clear the hurdle.

If you're in solid economic circumstances such that you could just as well get a visa for a tourist stay in a hotel, then attaching a Termo de Responsabilidade to your application would tend to *cast doubt on your application* rather than help it.

In your application you will need to detail how you intend to have a place to sleep, so you need to disclose you'll be staying a the friend's house, and an informal letter from the friend will be important to help demonstrate the realism of that plan. (A copy of his ID card might be considered overkill, but probably won't *hurt* now that you've got it).

However, if he attempts to "take responsibilty" in that letter rather than just confirm that he intends to offer accommodation, that might backfire too (in the sense of making your application look more desperate than you need it to be, making the consular officer suspicious). Depending on exactly how the letter looks, you might want him to write a different, more casual, one for you to enclose.

If your economic circumstances can support it, it may be useful to show that you can afford the stay *even if something happens so your friend cannot host you*. That much may be obvious from your bank statements, or you might enclose a worst-case budget for the case that you have a falling-out with your friend and need to walk up to a hotel and pay rack rate for the rest of your trip.